# Obtaining a property due to being part of a larger whole

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I'm looking for a word which describes obtaining a certain property due to being part of a larger whole.

E.g.

- a dinner set has a property "color". An instance of a dinner set could be white. Automatically, a dish, part of the dinner set, obtains this property. It has a white color, too.
- a sweater has a property "material". An instance of a sweater could be woolen. Automatically, a sleeve, part of the sweater, obtains this property. It has (been made of) material which is woolen, too.
- a people has a property "nationality". An instance of a people could be the English. Automatically, a person, part of the people, obtains this property. He has the English nationality, too.

How would you describe the implicit obtainment of these properties?

The closest I could think of was "inheritance".

Comment: *How did the sleeve of my all-green jumper "obtain the property" of being green?* Is that what you are asking? I am having difficulty understanding exactly what it is that we are trying to name.

Comment: *Inherit* works quite well for me, and chimes nicely with the "property" metaphor. The sleeve "inherits" the "property" *woolen* from its "parent" sweater.

Comment: If you refer object-oriented programming, [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29) is the standard term.

Comment: @Graffito actually it's not, because the is-a relationship implies inheritance. These are has-a relationships.

Comment: I never heard of a specific term to refer to a "parent object property".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question. After some thought, **derive** comes into mind.

[***Derive***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/derive)

> to receive or obtain from a source or origin / to trace from a source or origin

Comment: Yeah I think that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I dont't know if this is what you were looking for, but in some spheres (maths, phylosophy...), this is called the ['transitive property'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation). In general --and not too technical-- lines, given *a, b* and *c*, transitive property establishes that if *a* is related to *b* in a specific manner, and  *b* and *c* are also related, then *a* and *c* are related accordingly. Not too long ago, I heard something like this in the TV show called Silicon Valley, from an episode called Adult content. In a scene, EndFrame workers were claimed to be "pieces of sh-t". A certain "he" (I don't remember his name) worked for EndFrame "so, by the transitive property, he is, therefore, also a piece of sh-t." This sounded to me to resemble what you were trying to say. In your case, the transitive property would apply as follows:

- A given sweater (a) is made of woolen (b).
- A given sleeve (c) belongs to that sweater (a).
- Therefore, the sleeve (c) is made of woolen (b) too.

I thought maybe you could work something out from that (what about *transitivity* or something like that?).

Answer (score -1):

The person or thing has the property as a member of the given set *by definition*.